# Android - Screen Share using Agora.io

Tags: android, agora.io, screensharing

I am trying to implement **Screen Share** using **Agora.io** on Android. I tried to follow their demo however the solution using low level Android graphics API seems a bit too complex so I tried using ImageReader for this.

from my activity I create a service (**ShareScreenService** inheriting from Service)

to start screensharing there I do following

```
private void StartScreenShare(int resultCode, Intent resultData)
        {
            var mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager)GetSystemService(MediaProjectionService);
            var mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.GetMediaProjection(resultCode, resultData);
            _shareScreenImageAvailableListener = new ShareScreenImageAvailableListener(this);
            var virtualDisplay = mediaProjection.CreateVirtualDisplay("sharescreen", Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels, Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels, (int)Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi, DisplayFlags.SupportsProtectedBuffers | DisplayFlags.Presentation, _shareScreenImageAvailableListener.Surface, null, _handler);
            var mediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback(virtualDisplay);
            mediaProjection.RegisterCallback(mediaProjectionCallback, _handler);

            AgoraVideoService.Instance.StartScreenShare();
        }

AgoraVideoService.Instance.StartScreenShare does following:

internal void StartScreenShare()
        {
            _agoraEngine.SetExternalVideoSource(true, false, true);
        }
```

my **ShareScreenImageAvailableListener** looks like this:

```
public class ShareScreenImageAvailableListener : Java.Lang.Object, ImageReader.IOnImageAvailableListener
    {
        private ScreenShareService _screenShareService;
        private ImageReader _imageReader;

        public Surface Surface
        {
            get
            {
                return _imageReader.Surface;
            }
        }

        public ShareScreenImageAvailableListener(ScreenShareService screenShareService)
        {
            _screenShareService = screenShareService;
            _imageReader = ImageReader.NewInstance(_screenShareService.Width, _screenShareService.Height, Android.Graphics.ImageFormatType.Jpeg, 1);
            _imageReader.SetOnImageAvailableListener(this, _screenShareService.Handler);
        }

        public void OnImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
        {
            using (var image = reader.AcquireLatestImage())
            {
                using (var planes = image.GetPlanes()[0])
                {
                    using (var buffer = planes.Buffer)
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Capacity()];
                        buffer.Get(bytes);

                        _screenShareService.ShareScreenImage(bytes, image.Height, image.Format, planes.PixelStride);
                    }
                }
                image.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

then when sharing the **ShareScreenImage**:

```
internal void ShareScreenImage(byte[] bytes, int height, ImageFormatType format, int pixelStride)
        {
            var agoraVideoFrame = new AgoraVideoFrame()
            {
                Buf = bytes,
                Height = height,
                Format = (int)format,
                Stride = pixelStride,
                TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks,
               CropBottom = 0,
               CropLeft = 0,
               CropRight = 0,
               CropTop = 0
            };

            AgoraVideoService.Instance.ShareExternalVideoFrame(agoraVideoFrame);
        }
```

and lastly **ShareExternalVideoFrame** looks like this:

```
_agoraEngine.PushExternalVideoFrame(agoraVideoFrame);
```

**Finally, my question: is my thinking correct in terms of implementing this? Can I use ImageReader or do I need to go lower to start using EglCore etc. from Agora demo implementation?**

I can verify that OnImageAvailable is being called (multiple times until I stop it) **PushExternalVideoFrame** returns "true" which looks like the frames get pushed successfully

However this doesn't produce any results, I cannot see the screen being shared. So I would at least verify that this is a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safer to use EglCore because using ImageReader isn't something that is tested to work with Agora yet. You can use the advance guides and sample apps to get an idea on how to use it with EglCore.

Here's the link to the sample apps: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video

And here's the link to the guides: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/custom_video_android?platform=Android